# contents of javascript anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

With the Internet Explorer developer tools, I can inspect the value of an element's click method.  IE reports attached to it is an object (shows {...}).  However, I cannot see into the object (anonymous function).  Is there a way to see the contents of this?

Comment: Why not use Google Chrome or FireFox with Firebug plugin? They have much more powerfull tools then IE!

Comment: I am debugging a Microsoft CRM 2011 page which only works in Internet Explorer.  So I am stuck with the IE tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `the_function.toSource()` or any other "var_dump for JavaScript" equivalent?

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/759

http://phpjs.org/functions/var_dump:604

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use Firefox(with firebug) or Chrome? If not, I'd try seeing if using `the_function.toString()` works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I am debugging a Microsoft CRM 2011 page which only works in Internet Explorer.  So I am stuck with the IE tools.  I tried the toString() already, but it says it isn't a method on the object (which I find weird, b/c I thought all objects supported that in javascript).

Comment: I just checked here on my IE9 and functions do have toString. Perhaps your handler is some weird browser object or undefined (events added via AddEvent don't set the corresponding onX property). Check (typeof the_function) just in case.